# initialize data once in initState and call the setState when data is ready causes exception

Tags: flutter

Since flutter calls the build method many times in different condition, to avoid getting the data many times, I initialize the data in `initState`.

I want to re-build the widget when the data is ready.

Here is my code :

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TestState createState() => new _TestState();

}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {

  Data data;
  bool dataReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getData(context).then((Data data) async {
      setState(() {
        dataReady= true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (dataReady) {
      return createMainContent(context);
    } else {
      return new Container();
    }
  }

}
```

However, it results in following exception :

```
inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_InheritedProvider) or inheritFromElement() was called before _TestState.initState() completed.
```

May I know am I doing something wrong here?

When I add the following line to implementation of getData(context)

```
     await Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 300));
```

the exception does not happen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** Better answer below.

---

Apparently, **you cannot access `getData(context)` during `initState`** (more concrete: before it completed).

The reason, so I believe, is that `getData` tries to look up an `InheritedWidget` ancestor up in the tree, but the tree is just now being built (your widget is created during the parent widget's `build`).

The obvious solution would be to delay `getData`'s lookup to a later point in time. There are several ways to achieve that:

- Delay the lookup to a later time. `scheduleMicrotask` should work fine.
- Look it up during the first `build` call. You could have an `isInitialized` field set to `false` and in you `build`, something like:

  ```
  if (!isInitialized) {
    isInitialized = true;
    // TODO: do the getData(...) stuff
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi Marcel, many thanks for looking at my question. I am so sorry that my code is wrong, the line should be dataReady = true;. the exception still happens.

Comment: What does the exception say, now that you added `.catchError(print)` after the `.then(...)` call?

Comment: Hi Marcel, thanks for getting back to me again. I added the .catchError(print) after .then(...) call. there is no error in the getData(context) function. My exception is copied from flutter console output : E/flutter. I think it maybe related to the error while flutter is building this widget.

Comment: Okay, I edit my answer to reflect the content changes of your question.

Comment: You can also initialize a `Future` that holds your data in `initState` and then use a `FutureBuilder` in the `build` method. I have done this throughout my project and it has worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 18):

For everyone coming here at a later point

It is best to use the `@override void didChangeDependencies ()` method of the `State` class.

From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin/didChangeDependencies.html)

> This method is also called immediately after initState. It is safe to call BuildContext.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType from this method.

But make sure to check if you have already performed your initialization

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  if (bloc == null) { // or else you end up creating multiple instances in this case.
    bloc = BlocProvider<MyBloc>.of(context);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excelent Approach.

Answer (score 9):

an alternative is to put it inside `PostFrameCallback` which is between `initState` and `Build`.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getData());
    super.initState();
  }

  getData() async {

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved my code to my build method from initState and it worked

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {

  Data data;
  bool dataReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData(context).then((Data data) async {
      setState(() {
        dataReady= true;
      });
    });
    if (dataReady) {
      return createMainContent(context);
    } else {
      return new Container();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: this is not the correct approach as getData will be called every time the widget gets built