# inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(InheritedProvider<ConnectivityStatus>) or inheritFromElement() was called before

Tags: flutter, dart

In this simple class i want to make base state class to manage some actions such as accessing to internet connection:

```
abstract class BaseState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State {
  bool isOnline;
  ConnectivityStatus _connectivityStatus;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _connectivityStatus = Provider.of<ConnectivityStatus>(context);
    isOnline = _connectivityStatus == ConnectivityStatus.Connected;
    if (!isOnline) {
      showSimpleNotification(Text("disconnected"), background: Colors.green);
    } else {
      showSimpleNotification(Text("connected"), background: Colors.red);
    }
  }
}
```

when i try to use this class like with:

```
class _FragmentLoginState extends BaseState<FragmentLogin> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  PageController _pageController;
  Color left = Colors.black;
  Color right = Colors.white;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 1);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you don't have a valid Context yet.

you can try theses two solution

- defer using context:

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initConnectivity();
  }

  Future _initConnectivity() async {
    await Future.delayad(Duration.zero);
    _connectivityStatus = Provider.of<ConnectivityStatus>(context);
    isOnline = _connectivityStatus == ConnectivityStatus.Connected;
    if (!isOnline) {
      showSimpleNotification(Text("disconnected"), background: Colors.green);
    } else {
      showSimpleNotification(Text("connected"), background: Colors.red);
    }
  }
```

- move your logic in the build function ( in BaseState )

```dart
_initConnectivity() {
    _connectivityStatus = Provider.of<ConnectivityStatus>(context);
    isOnline = _connectivityStatus == ConnectivityStatus.Connected;
    if (!isOnline) {
      showSimpleNotification(Text("disconnected"), background: Colors.green);
    } else {
      showSimpleNotification(Text("connected"), background: Colors.red);
    }
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _initConnectivity();
  }
```

in the second method you can also create a flag like `isFirstBuild` to make sure it runs only one time.

also these may help :

- [initialize data once in initState and call the setState when data is ready causes exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52828815/initialize-data-once-in-initstate-and-call-the-setstate-when-data-is-ready-cause)
- [Flutter get context in initState method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457717/flutter-get-context-in-initstate-method)

Answer (score 1):

[Use a frame callback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) which delays execution until the next frame (i.e. after initState has complete)

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      _connectivityStatus = Provider.of<ConnectivityStatus>(context);
      isOnline = _connectivityStatus == ConnectivityStatus.Connected;
      if (!isOnline) {
        showSimpleNotification(Text("disconnected"), background: Colors.green);
      } else {
        showSimpleNotification(Text("connected"), background: Colors.red);
      }
    });
  }
```